# How to target a ref inside a component from another component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am experiencing some problem with my communication between React.Components, and i was hoping, that someone could help me out.

I have created a component Container, which holds a lot of other child component, say Contact, More, About and so on (I am making a single-page-website, hence the Container class). In these children components i have set a reference. Now comes the problem. I am trying to fetch these child components from another component NavigationBar because i need to use them for a "scroll-to-component"-feature, but i cant figure how to target them.

Can anyone help me out? I have provided some exemplary code below, where i want to use the ref in the scrollToComponent method in the navigation Links:

```
import Home from './ui/Home';
import About from './ui/About';
import Contact from './ui/Contact';
export default class Container extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Home ref={(Component) => { this.Home = Component; }} />
    <About ref={(Component) => { this.About = Component; }} />
    <Contact ref={(Component) => { this.Contact = Component; }} />
  </div>
)}};


export default class Navigationbar extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <Link to="/"><img src={HomeIcon} alt="home-button"
                onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.refs.Home))}/>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about"><img src={AboutIcon} alt="about-button" 
                onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.refs.About))}
            /></Link>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you place your Navigationbar component inside your container. Then you could simply pass the refs as props to the Navigationbar. So for example, you could try this:

```
import Home from './ui/Home';
import About from './ui/About';
import Contact from './ui/Contact';
import Navigationbar from './pathtp/navigationbar';
export default class Container extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Navigationbar
      homeRef={this.Home}
      aboutRef={this.About}
      contactRef={this.Contact}
    />
    <div>
      <Home ref={(Component) => { this.Home = Component; }} />
      <About ref={(Component) => { this.About = Component; }} />
      <Contact ref={(Component) => { this.Contact = Component; }} />
    </div>
  </div>
)}};
```

And in your Navigationbar component:

```
export default class Navigationbar extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <Link to="/"><img src={HomeIcon} alt="home-button"
                onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.props.homeRef))}/>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about"><img src={AboutIcon} alt="about-button" 
                onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.props.aboutRef))}
            /></Link>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working, except for one tiny thing. The links sometimes needs multiple click before triggering the event. Do you have any clue why this is the case?

Comment: I am not really sure why this is the case. Might be related to the DOM rendering. Refs become alive once the DOM is rendered. Before that they should be null. It might be interesting to console.log the refs in your onClick handler, to see whether the refs have been loaded correctly.

If my answer helped you, it would be nice if you would mark it as accepted and gibe it an upvote ;) Thanks

Comment: Yes i will gladly up-vote it. When i console.log the ref, it says undefined on the click that does not work, and then suddenly it works and it prints the right prop. Do you know a solution to this problem? :D

Comment: Yeah, thats what i was expecting. To my knowledge, you cannot really do anything about that because you have to wait for the DOM to finish rendering in order to work with the refs. But if all you ant to accomplish is scrolling, you might give react-scroll a try. It's an npm package designed to do exactly that ;)

Comment: Thanks ! But as far as I can see, the react-scroll package does not support the feature of scrolling to a specific component, or am I wrong?

Comment: It does, you can target elements with className using the "to" prop